# FileNotFound error, but i have the txt file in the same location as the java file

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

So I have this program that should read a txt file about an item inventory, problem is when i run it i get this "The file inventory.txt was not found.", i have it all in the same folder, the java file, class file, and txt file, but nothing happens still. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class InventoryItem {
   private String name;
   private int units;   // number of available units of this item
   private float price;  // price per unit of this item
   private DecimalFormat fmt;
   public InventoryItem (String itemName, int numUnits, float cost) {
      name = itemName;
      units = numUnits;
      price = cost;
      fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");
   }
   public String toString()   {
      return name + ":\t" + units + " at " + price + " = " +
             fmt.format ((units * price));
   }
}
public class Inventory{
   //  Reads data about a store inventory from an input file,
   //  creating an array of InventoryItem objects, then prints them.
   public static void main (String[] args)   {
      final int MAX = 100;
      InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[MAX];
      StringTokenizer tokenizer;
      String line, name, file="inventory.txt";
      int units, count = 0;
      float price;

      try{
         FileReader fr = new FileReader (file);
         BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader (fr);
         line = inFile.readLine();
         while (line != null) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer (line);
            name = tokenizer.nextToken();
            try            {
               units = Integer.parseInt (tokenizer.nextToken());
               price = Float.parseFloat (tokenizer.nextToken());
               items[count++] = new InventoryItem (name, units, price);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException exception)            {
               System.out.println ("Error in input. Line ignored:");
               System.out.println (line);
            }
            line = inFile.readLine();
         }
         inFile.close();

                 for (int scan = 0; scan < count; scan++)
                     System.out.println (items[scan]);
               }
               catch (FileNotFoundException exception)      {
                  System.out.println ("The file " + file + " was not found.");
               }
               catch (IOException exception)      {
                  System.out.println (exception);
               }
            }
         }
```

and now here is the txt file i want it to read:

```
Widget 14 3.35 Spoke 132 0.32 Wrap 58 1.92 Thing 28 4.17 Brace 25 1.75 Clip 409 0.12 Cog 142 2.08
```

EDIT: My bad I didn't specify the directory, so have my files in my downloads file so the path is this cd\users\person\downloads. I have the Inventory.java, Inventory.class and inventory.txt here

Comment: `file="inventory.txt";` try `file = "src/inventory.txt;"`

Comment: It needs to be in the current working directory for that filename to work. Nothing to do with the source directory, which won't be there at runtime when deployed. Maybe you should access it as a resource?

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new folder, we'll call it "texts" for now. Then, you code would be like:

```
//your code here
String line, name, file="texts\\inventory.txt";
//more code
```

Hope this helped!